# RabbitMQ HA durable mirrored queues, outage during ungraceful shutdown of the primary node

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

### RabbitMQ HA durable mirrored queues, outage during ungraceful shutdown of the primary node

We have a couple of RabbitMQ HA durable mirrored queues running on some VM clusters, when we power off abruptly the node hosting the primary queues, we saw that the publish/consume is getting stopped for a few minutes and resuming again. Why is this behaviour happening?